# Is it a good idea to separate the Database and the website files in 2 shared hosting?

Tags: performance, shared-hosting, scalability

Do you think If I did separate the db and the files will make it performs better? and is this easy thing to do? What if I upgrade later on to 2 VPS as well, can I do the same thing without affecting both?

Comment: How is this remotely possible to answer when you're not explainin what your performance problems (if any) are today? How many visitors, how high load on your single server, how many processing cores/threads etc

Comment: without performance issues at the moment, if I did that will it perofrm better?

Comment: "97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using shared hosting, your database and your site is most likely already on seperate machines and you will not benefit from a second shared account.

If you upgrade your shared hosting to a VPS you probably have to install both the webserver and database server yourself. But you have to benchmark your site to see if you need a bigger VPS or a dedicated server for the database.